# Find the gradient of a graph at the y axis

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question gave the equation:
$y^3+2y = \sin x+\cos x-1+3x^{2}$ and then asked to find the gradient of the curve at the points when the graph cuts the y axis.

I am not sure how to approach this.
Maybe let $x = 0$?

If we do then we get $y(y^{2}+2)= 0$ so $y = 0$?

Then maybe find the derivative using implicit differentiation but not sure how far that would get us?

Thanks.

Comment: You have outlined a correct approach. Do it!

Comment: would you then find the derivative of both sides implicitly and then from the derivative you plug in x = 0, y = 0?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As a check, you should end up with slope $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yay, got it! Thanks alot. I wasn't sure if you could make x = 0 to find y-intercepts if there wasn't an explicit relation between x and y.

Comment: Or rather that there wasn't a y = ...

Comment: It is not in principle obvious that there is a $y$-intercept. But if there is, setting $x=0$ and solving for $y$ will find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solving for gradient [i.e. "slope"] at $x = 0$ ($x = 0$ is that is the equation of the y-axis) given 
$\;y^3+2y = \sin x+\cos x-1+3x^{2}\tag{1}$

- Solve for $y$ at $x = 0$: $\quad x = 0 \implies y^3 + 2y = y(y^2 + 2) = 0\implies y = 0, \;x, y \in \mathbb R$
- Use implicit differentiation on the left hand side and the right hand side: as a check, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{6x + \cos x - \sin x}{3y^2 + 2}$$
- Evaluating the derivative at $(0, 0)$ will give the slope/gradient $m$ of the curve at the $y\text{-intercept}.\;$ As a check: we should get $m = 1/2.$

---

And here, in fact, is the graph of your function near the origin, and a graph of your function with the line tangent to the curve at $(0, 0)$

$\quad\quad$[image]

$\quad\quad$[image]

Comment: Nice Amy, for your graphs :+)

Comment: Good morning! How are you? I'm having a very slow night again :-(

Comment: Good one to you dear friend. I was too. :-( But never mind it will be OK. :-)