# Equation of a curve at a given point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following problem of differential equations in geometry:

> The gradient at any point of a curve is [an equation]. If the curve passes through the point $(x, y)$ determine it's equation.

If I interpreted correctly, would that be, given the equation of the curve $f(x)$ and a point $x_0$, determine if the curve passes through the given point and if it does, determine the function of the gradient?

Comment: Your definition of the gradient is incorrect, please look it up

Comment: @yuriy-s I made a mistake but that is the general equation for the gradiente of a curve at a given point.

Comment: No, what you have written is $\partial_x f(x,y)$, a partial derivative. And even then, the definition is incorrect

Comment: What are you actually trying to write? Please look up the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient

Comment: @yuriy-y Let me know now if I have it correct. If not, could you please make the necessary suggestions.

Comment: Please follow the link where you can look up the definition for the gradient, then edit your question. What you have so far is not a correct defintion for anything

Comment: @yuriy-y I think I misinterpreted the problem. Could you please check again and provide me with any recommendations?

Comment: Given the slope at each point, determine the curve that passes through (a,b). Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for [how to find the flow of a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101145/find-the-flow-of-a-vector-field) through a point.

Comment: @WilliamElliot My problem is that I do not fully understand the given problem. Would that be your interpretation of it?

Comment: @William Elliott "Gradient" in this context means  "slope" (see, e.g., amWhy's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328746/find-the-gradient-of-a-graph-at-the-y-axis).  So, William Elliott's interpretation is right.